# restart error with no output

Tags: python, restart

I'm new to coding, I'm trying to replicate a code for a simple calculator, when I try to run the module is gives me a restart error and nothing happens

code is

```
from tkinter import*

def frame(root, side):
    w=Frame(root)
    w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return w

def button(root,side,text, command=None):
    w=Button(root,text=text, command=command)
    w.pack(side=side, expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    return w

class Calculator(Frame):
    def __init__ (self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.tittle('simple Calculator')
        self.master.iconname('calcl')

        display = StringVar()
        Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN,
              textvariable=display).pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        for key in ('123', '456', '789' '-0'):
            keyF= frame(self, TOP)
            for char in ket:
                button (keyF, LEFT, char, lambda w=display, s='%s '%char:w.set(w.get()+s))
            opsF= frame(self, TOP)
            for char in '+-/*=':
                if char=='=':
                    btn=button(opsF, LEFT, char)
                    btn.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e, s=self, w=display: s.calc(w), '+')
                else:
                    btn=button (opsF, LEFT, char, lambda w=display, c=chair: w.set(w.get()+' '+c+' '))
            clearF = frame (self, BOTTOM)
            button(clearF, LEFT, 'CLr', lambda w=display: w.set(''))

    def calc(self, display):
        try:
             display.set('eval(display.get())')
        except ValueError:
                 display.set('ERROR')

if __name__ == 'main__':
    Calculator().mainloop()
```

error :

> = RESTART: C:\Users\sibiyass\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\calc1.py =

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error.

The line

```
= RESTART: C:\Users\sibiyass\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\calc1.py =
```

says that python is restarting your code and it shows the path of your code under file name `calc1.py`

It is restarting because your code is not producing any output.

And your program was not producing any output because there were many keyword errors. I would suggest that you run your code by replacing `if __name__ == '__main__'` by `main()` and wrapping `Calculator().mainloop()` inside the definition of `main()`. Keep correcting the code.

To be specific, your code has following errors:

1) On the line 33, `chair` should be `char`

2) On the line 17, `tittle` should be 'title'

3) On the line 25, `ket` should be `key`

Your modified code should look like:

```
from tkinter import*

def frame(root, side):
    w=Frame(root)
    w.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return w

def button(root,side,text, command=None):
    w=Button(root,text=text, command=command)
    w.pack(side=side, expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    return w

class Calculator(Frame):
    def __init__ (self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('simple Calculator')
        self.master.iconname('calcl')

        display = StringVar()
        Entry(self, relief=SUNKEN,
              textvariable=display).pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        for key in ('123', '456', '789' '-0'):
            keyF= frame(self, TOP)
            for char in key:
                button (keyF, LEFT, char, lambda w=display, s='%s '%char:w.set(w.get()+s))
            opsF= frame(self, TOP)
            for char in '+-/*=':
                if char=='=':
                    btn=button(opsF, LEFT, char)
                    btn.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',lambda e, s=self, w=display: s.calc(w), '+')
                else:
                    btn=button (opsF, LEFT, char, lambda w=display, c=char: w.set(w.get()+' '+c+' '))
            clearF = frame (self, BOTTOM)
            button(clearF, LEFT, 'CLr', lambda w=display: w.set(''))

    def calc(self, display):
        try:
             display.set('eval(display.get())')
        except ValueError:
                 display.set('ERROR')

def main():
    Calculator().mainloop()

main()
```

Try running it.